# nemo action does not extend variable inside 'Exec='

Tags: bash, shell-script, linux-mint

I have created a Nemo file manager action inside `/home/blueray/.local/share/nemo/actions`

The action looks like:

```
[Nemo Action]
Name=Show Desktop
Comment=Show Desktop
Exec=notify-send "$HOME/Desktop"
Icon-Name=edit-copy-symbolic
Selection=notnone
Extensions=any;
EscapeSpaces=true
```

The problem is, it shows `$HOME/Desktop` instead of `/home/blueray/Desktop`

what can I do?

Comment: use absolute path, these actions doesn't know about shell environment variables to expand, or write within script and call your script in `Exec` action instead

Comment: or maybe `Exec=/bin/bash -c 'notify-send "$HOME/Desktop"'`?